# Filter Data between Sunset and Sunrise

Tags: r, datetime, filter

There is already an answer to similar question but it addresses sorting between sunrise and sunset, not night time hours sunset through sunrise.

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 278,461 × 9
   datetime            longitude latitude count date         lat   lon sunrise             sunset             
   <dttm>                  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 2021-09-01 00:00:00     -92.5     36.2  9.18 2021-09-01  36.2 -92.3 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 2 2021-09-01 01:00:00     -92.6     36.4 13.3  2021-09-01  36.2 -92.3 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 3 2021-09-01 01:00:00     -92.5     36.3 18.5  2021-09-01  36.2 -92.3 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 4 2021-09-01 01:00:00     -92.5     36.2  9.18 2021-09-01  36.2 -92.3 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 5 2021-09-01 02:00:00     -92.5     36.3 20.2  2021-09-01  36.2 -92.3 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 6 2021-09-01 03:00:00     -92.5     36.2 21.7  2021-09-01  36.2 -92.3 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 7 2021-09-01 03:00:00     -92.5     36.2  9.18 2021-09-01  36.2 -92.3 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 8 2021-09-01 03:00:00     -92.5     36.2  9.18 2021-09-01  36.2 -92.3 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 9 2021-09-01 04:00:00     -92.5     36.2  9.18 2021-09-01  36.2 -92.3 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
10 2021-09-01 05:00:00     -92.5     36.2  9.18 2021-09-01  36.2 -92.3 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56

df <- tibble(
  datetime = as.POSIXct(c("2021-09-01 00:00:00", "2021-09-01 01:00:00", "2021-09-01 01:00:00", "2021-09-01 01:00:00", "2021-09-01 02:00:00", "2021-09-01 03:00:00", "2021-09-01 03:00:00", "2021-09-01 03:00:00", "2021-09-01 04:00:00", "2021-09-01 05:00:00")),
  longitude = c(-92.5, -92.6, -92.5, -92.5, -92.5, -92.5, -92.5, -92.5, -92.5, -92.5),
  latitude = c(36.2, 36.4, 36.3, 36.2, 36.3, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2, 36.2),
  count = c(9.18, 13.3, 18.5, 9.18, 20.2, 21.7, 9.18, 9.18, 9.18, 9.18),
  date = as.Date(rep("2021-09-01", 10)),
  lat = rep(36.2, 10),
  lon = rep(-92.3, 10),
  sunrise = as.POSIXct("2021-09-01 07:42:27"),
  sunset = as.POSIXct("2021-09-01 20:38:56")
)
```

The issue is filtering for hours between sunset and sunrise because of the formatting in milatary time. If i use:

`filter(sunset <= datetime, datetime <= sunrise)`

Then it filters all the data out and I end up with a dateframe with 0 observations. How can I filter the data so I have hours greater than sunset and less than sunrise in the same dataframe?

Comment: You need an "OR" operation in there.  Try: `filter(sunset <= datetime | datetime <= sunrise)`.  The comma is acting an "AND" operation.  The time can't be < sunrise AND > sunset.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [between](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/1.0.10/topics/between):

```
# create a toy data frame
df <- tibble(
  datetime = seq(as.POSIXct("2021-09-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2021-09-01 23:59:59"), by = "1 hour"),
  sunrise = as.POSIXct("2021-09-01 07:42:27"),
  sunset = as.POSIXct("2021-09-01 20:38:56")
)
dplyr::filter(df, between(datetime, sunrise, sunset))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 13 × 3
   datetime            sunrise             sunset             
   <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 2021-09-01 08:00:00 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 2 2021-09-01 09:00:00 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 3 2021-09-01 10:00:00 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 4 2021-09-01 11:00:00 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 5 2021-09-01 12:00:00 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 6 2021-09-01 13:00:00 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 7 2021-09-01 14:00:00 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 8 2021-09-01 15:00:00 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
 9 2021-09-01 16:00:00 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
10 2021-09-01 17:00:00 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
11 2021-09-01 18:00:00 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
12 2021-09-01 19:00:00 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
13 2021-09-01 20:00:00 2021-09-01 07:42:27 2021-09-01 20:38:56
```